# Topological disorder in condensed matter?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order

What is meant by [topological disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order) in condensed matter (both crystalline and amorphous)?

For example, please see the following two papers from arxiv.org

http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3848

http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0308612v1

Thanks

Comment: It would probably help to update the question with some details about your background. I know next to nothing about this stuff but I would guess topological disorder is related to (possibly a synonym of) [topological entanglement entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy_(in_physics)). It's probably also related to [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order) (though after reading that article I still don't really know what that means.)

Comment: By the way, your first link is incorrect. It says "topological disorder" but the link goes to a wikipedia page on topological order. Based on what I could gather from the arXiv papers, I don't think topological disorder and order are used in the same context; i.e. one is not the absence of the other.

Comment: The first link was not added by me. It was edited by someone else.